# How could I play the Siri sound from code

Tags: ios, audio, siri

I would like to play the Siri sound legally. I thought I could use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound but I do not know the sound ID, can you think of another way?

Comment: Use `Sirikit` to do. I don't think its available anywhere.